# Looping ground tile as character moves in unity 2D

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine, tile

I am trying to create a ground tile that, once is off screen moves to the forward position in front of the other ground tile that is currently in the screen.

[image]

I have barely tried anything in code that would be even slightly useful to add to this question. Could someone point me in the right direction to be able to get this done so I don't have to just duplicate hundreds of tiles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Attach this scrip on your `Tile`object.

```
using UnityEngine;

    public class SpawnTiles : MonoBehaviour {

        private Material currentTile;
        public float speed;
        private float offset;


        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

            currentTile = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

            offset += 0.001f;
            currentTile.SetTextureOffset ("_MainTex", new Vector2 (offset * speed, 0));
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

[This is what you want?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgNlXJQNY1w)

If YES, follow theses steps.

Create > 3D Object > Quad (Resize as you want)

[image]

Select your tile sprite:

Texture type = texture

Wrap mode = repeat

[image]

Now creat new `Material`: Create > Material

Select: Shader = Unlit/Texture

Texture select your previous texture.

[image]

Drag and drop this `Material` inside `Quad`object.

[image]

Adjust tiles at inspector.

[image]

Result

[image]

Creat new scrip `SpawnTiles` and attach at `Quad`object.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnTiles : MonoBehaviour {

    private Material currentTile;
    public float speed;
    private float offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (Time.time * speed, 0f);
    }
}
```

Ajust tiles movement speed at inspector.

Finish rename `Quad`object as you want.

[image]

Comment: I am not using a texture on the object, it is a sprite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only move the back tile to the front, you probably don't need it, but I still highly suggest looking into [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).

To detect if a camera can't see the tile, use [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html): `Renderer.isVisible`

To move the tile, if all the tiles are the same dimensions, you could just increase it's position.x by the amount you need.

Comment: I tried using Renderer.isVisible and to check it out I put a debug.log() and it said false for 2 frames and then true for the rest. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution using WorldPointToViewport().

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class groundTilingScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform ground; //For reference to the transform 
    Camera cam; //Reference to Main Camera

    float groundWidth; //The width of the transform, used for calculating current max x position of transform and next placement x position
    private float nextXPos = 0.0f; //Store next x position in variable for easier reading

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //Set up References
        ground = transform;
        cam = Camera.main;

        //Store Ground width (Width of the ground tile)
        groundWidth = ground.GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Create new Vector3 to be used in WorldToViewportPoint so it doesn't use the middle of the ground as reference
        Vector3 boxRightPos = new Vector3 (ground.position.x + groundWidth/2, ground.position.y, ground.position.z);

        //Store view Position of ground
        Vector3 viewPos = cam.WorldToViewportPoint (boxRightPos);

        //If the ground tile is left of camera viewport
        if (viewPos.x < 0) {
            //gameObject is offscreen, destroy it and re-instantiate it at new xPosition
            float currentRightX = ground.position.x + groundWidth;
            nextXPos = currentRightX + groundWidth;


            Instantiate (gameObject, new Vector3 (nextXPos, ground.position.y, ground.position.z), ground.rotation);

            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

NOTE: I have to set up two ground tiles initially to give room for camera to go further than the ground tile. (One tile on screen, one off)

Again, this is just my attempt. I am completely open to criticism.

Comment: Look my Edit and check if can help you! Good luck.

Comment: That works, I was just looking for best solution by using purely a sprite with no texture... But Thanks for the edit!